# Trying to copy my documents folder using powershell

Tags: powershell

```
$dir = Read-Host 'Please enter the letter drive to backup user folder.'
copy-item ($env:USERPROFILE+"\Documents") -destination ($dir+":\Backup")   -recurse
```

I"m trying to copy my documents folder, however when I look in the backup folder I see that it copies my pictures and my videos as well. In addition to that I get the following errors:

```
Copy-Item : Access to the path 'C:\Users\admin\Documents\My Music' is denied.
At C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Untitled1.ps1:2 char:10
+ copy-item <<<<  ($env:USERPROFILE+"\Documents") -destination ($dir+":\Backup") -recurse
+ CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (My Music:DirectoryInfo) [Copy-Item], UnauthorizedAccessException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CopyDirectoryInfoItemUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand

Copy-Item : Access to the path 'C:\Users\admin\Documents\My Pictures' is denied.
At C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Untitled1.ps1:2 char:10
+ copy-item <<<<  ($env:USERPROFILE+"\Documents") -destination ($dir+":\Backup") -recurse
+ CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (My Pictures:DirectoryInfo) [Copy-Item], UnauthorizedAccessException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CopyDirectoryInfoItemUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand

Copy-Item : Access to the path 'C:\Users\admin\Documents\My Videos' is denied.
At C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Untitled1.ps1:2 char:10
+ copy-item <<<<  ($env:USERPROFILE+"\Documents") -destination ($dir+":\Backup") -recurse
+ CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (My Videos:DirectoryInfo) [Copy-Item], UnauthorizedAccessException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CopyDirectoryInfoItemUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

It also makes a user folder in the root of the selected drive.

Comment: Those links are actually symbolic links for legacy applications.  Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21514284/parsing-shortcuts-in-powershell

Comment: You usually don't need those symbolic links (they only exist for backcompat for legacy and poorly written Windows apps), and Copy should have succeeded on everything else.  Did you verify that the copy didn't actually work despite the error messages?  One quick and dirty way to remove the errors is `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`, but be careful as it will also suppress legitimate errors.

Answer (score 1):

This may work better for you. You currently might be parsing sym links rather than getting the actual path. Using this method will get the actual folder path every time.

```
$dir = Read-Host 'Please enter the letter drive to backup user folder.'
copy-item -Path [environment]::getfolderpath('mydocuments') -destination ($dir+":\Backup") -Recurse
```

Comment: I don't think this solves the problem of errors when it encounters reparse points.  This answer provides a better way of getting the path to the *Documents* folder, but in the end it's executing exactly the same `copy-item` command.  Can you expand this answer to explain how this is different from OP's code, and how it solves the problem?

Comment: Expanded a little. It's not exactly the same. It prevents the sym link problem that user4317867 commented on.